# PHP - Unable to change memory_limit on php-fpm

Tags: php

It might seem a stupid question, but I'm already trying since one hour to figure it out without success.

As stated in title, I'm actually unable to change `memory_limit` directive in PHP 7.1.15 but **only for php-fpm**. In fact if I execute `php -i | grep memory_limit` in terminal I can see the correct value `memory_limit => -1 => -1`.

What I tried so far:

- Setting `memory_limit` in php.ini
- Using `ini_set('memory_limit', -1);` directly in PHP script

I also tried to disable all loaded extensions cause I thought maybe one of them is overwriting that setting, but didn't work.

Also consider that edited php.ini file is the correct one since I was able to change `max_execution_time` without any problem.

So how this code

```
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
echo ini_get('memory_limit');
exit;
```

can return `128M` as output?

Comment: Try setting `php_admin_value[memory_limit] = -1` within your `php-fpm.conf` file.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much! You can write it as answer :)

Comment: Also would be nice to know in this situation how could I set `memory_limit` at runtime..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the memory limit for PHP-FPM, add the following line to your `php-fpm.conf` file:

```
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

from fpm-config

```
;   php_value/php_flag             - you can set classic ini defines which can
;                                    be overwritten from PHP call 'ini_set'.
;   php_admin_value/php_admin_flag - these directives won't be overwritten by
;                                     PHP call 'ini_set'
```

You must chose better solution for you. I'm prefer set lower memory limit in global config, and in places (wo I can't rewrite better) I'm add `ini_set('memory_limit', xxx);`