# why is memory_limit in php.ini not updating memory size?

Tags: php, docker, ini

Good day!

I am using the `php: 8.0-rc-fpm` image for my `php-fpm` container. Also I am using the `intrusion` library to generate and process images. The problem is that there is not enough memory and every time I get an error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24576 bytes)

this means that the server does not have enough 128MB of data, but when I add the `memory.ini` entry to the file
`'' memory_limit = 512 MB` ''
then the actual value of the limit does not change. If you enter the command inside the container:

```
php -r "echo ini_get ('memory_limit'). PHP_EOL;"
```

then i get the answer

```
512M
```

Comment: translate the title, please.

Comment: It's fine that you tell PHP that it has 512M to play with, but did you tell *Docker* that, also?

Comment: @MikeRobinson Didn't say anything to Docker. Does the default container have resource limits?

Comment: Is the primary use case also running from command line? If it’s running under Apache, or some other persistent form, you’d need to restart the server in order for the change to stick. Also if running in a persistent state, there may be memory limits related to the parent process.

Comment: Try running phpinfo() from the same environment where you’re running out of memory.

Comment: @EricShieh  displayed information about my php-fpm container and this is what he told me:
memory usage / limit
174.7MiB / 11.99GiB

Comment: @EricShieh phpinfo() say -> memory_limit 128M 128M

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601972/php-unable-to-change-memory-limit-on-php-fpm